# ARCore: Am I restrained to using large, flat surfaces?

Tags: arcore

I know that ARCore can detect flat surfaces like floors and tables, but can it detect other, less regular objects? Say I have a chair and a stool sitting on the ground in front of me. Could ARCore detect these 2 objects in any way? Am I restrained to using large, flat surfaces when designing AR experiences with ARCore?

If there is any documentation about detecting real-world objects I would much appreciate a pointer to it.

Any advice would be helpful. :) Thanks.

Comment: It may help to read this post regarding ARKit: https://medium.com/super-ventures-blog/why-is-arkit-better-than-the-alternatives-af8871889d6a to get a better idea of the issues involved.

Answer (score 1):

ARCore can only detect horizontal surfaces at the moment.  Vertical surfaces like walls and objects are not supported.

However, Tango devices have better support through extra hardware like dual cameras and infrared sensors
Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFbcOGuDMPk